# Piecewise function not evaluating properly

Tags: plotting, evaluation, piecewise

I have a simple `Piecewise` function that defines a square pulse:

```
f[x_] := 
 Piecewise[{
  {0, x < -(1/2)},
  {1/2, x == -(1/2)},
  {1, -(1/2) < x < 1/2}, 
  {1/2, x == 1/2},
  {0, x > 1/2}
 }]
```

However, `Plot` produces a non-joined-up graph:

```
Plot[f[x], {x, -1, 1}, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Mathematica seems to be ignoring the definition `f[x] = {1/2, x == -(1/2)}`. But I want to specify that `f` takes half-values at the discontinuities.

Why is Mathematica happy at `x = 1/2` but not at `x = -(1/2)`? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add `Exclusions -> None` to the `Plot`

Comment: Thanks @MarcoB. Can you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding `Exclusions -> None` will take care of that:

```
Plot[f[x], {x, -1, 1}, GridLines -> Automatic, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image: plot without discontinuities]